# Event Grid subscription webhook that exists in vpn

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

We would like to use Event Grid for pub/sub system with webhook where some of the subscriber's endpoints live in Azure's private virtual network. These web endpoints are not exposed to the internet and we have IP restrictions set to our private network's IP ranges. Is there a way to provision event grid within azure's virtual network so it can connect to these endpoints? From what I have read, this isn't doable right out of the box. The options I can think of: stand up functions that are internet facing but can connect to vpn, use queue as endpoint instead of webhooks (with either subscriber directly retrieving from queue or have another set of functions that are not internet facing, that is triggered off of queue to call our internal endpoints). Are there other options that I'm missing? Which approach is the recommended approach in this situation?

Comment: have a look at the Azure Hybrid Connections https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

Answer (score 2):

As of now there is no possibility of keeping Event grid in a private network as it violates its design. If you are looking for a secure communication then you can use [Azure app service Hybrid connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) feature which would be a public endpoint for accessing Event grid. You can even up-vote for this feature in the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909934-azure-event-grid/suggestions/37993987-allow-webhooks-to-be-delivered-into-vnets) section for its availability.